# How do I ignore the alpha content when loading an Image off disk into a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Currently, when I load an image off disk,

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("myfile.png");
```

The resulting color space is one of ARGB. What I'd prefer is a plain old RGB, but without having to do the filtering myself.

Is there a way to open an image in a certain color mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to open it with a specific color format, but you can create a new BufferedImage of the desired format and draw the old image on to it:

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = img2.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

Any transparent parts in the original image will be drawn over a black background in the new image. If you'd prefer a different background, you can insert these lines before the `drawImage` call:

```
g.setColor(Color.white); // or whichever
g.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
```

Comment: Yep, just beware that the default background is black +1